# Отправка mail сообщения из скрипта bash sh

Tags: bash, email, sh

Помогите решить задачу, требуется отправить уведомление на мейл если ресурс не пингуется

```
#!/bin/bash

FP="/var/www/vhosts/site.ru/httpdocs/local/logs"
for i in site.ru
do
    ping -c4 -q $i
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        ps -auxf >> "$FP/ping_`date +%Y%m%d`_`date +%H%M`.log"
        /opt/plesk/php/8.1/bin/php -r "mail('mail@gmail.com', '$i is not available!', '$(ps -auxf)');" &>> "$FP/mail.log"
        break
    fi
done
```

Не могу понять как правильно передать текстом письма в `mail $(ps -auxf)`, пробовал сначала в переменную сохранять

```sh
PS=$(ps -auxf)
```

и потом писать так

```sh
"mail('mail@gmail.com', '$i is not available!', '$PS');"
```

не помогло...

Comment: Gmail не принимает письма от неизвестных серверов. Даже если вам удастся отправить письмо, входящий SMTP сервер подавляющего большинства почтовых сервисов такое письмо отвергнет. Проще будет вам поднять [бота в телеграме](https://www.labnol.org/telegram-bot-notifications-210814) и слать уведомления через него

Comment: на yandex например через его че smtp сервер приходит норм, вопрос был не в этом, а в том как передать $(ps -auxf)

Comment: Попробуйте какой-нибудь консольный mail агент, я для подобных целей использовал `mutt` т.к. он умеет отправлять с attachment.

Comment: Ваш вариант будет выглядеть как-то так: `PS=$(ps -auxf); mutt -s "$subjct" "$mailto" <<< "$PS"`